# Is there any way we can replace data of single fragment without replacing fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tvItem.setText(itemList.get(position).getmTitle());
    Picasso.get().load(itemList.get(position).geturl()).into(holder.imgFlag);
    final ModelClass model= itemList.get(position);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DataFragment dataFragment= new DataFragment();
            ((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment,dataFragment)
                    .commit();
                    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("model", model);
                    dataFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code we will help you

Comment: I have used a fragment which show data when recyclerview is clicked. I want to ask that if we want to update data on click of recyclerview but fragment is not replaced how it will done?
Is there any method or interface which we use?

Comment: I have added code please check

Comment: do you want to update data when recyclerview item clicked right?

Comment: yes I want to update

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method on your fragment that you use to update it, and use that if the fragment already exists.

Example:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final myViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.tvItem.setText(itemList.get(position).getmTitle());
    Picasso.get().load(itemList.get(position).geturl()).into(holder.imgFlag);
    final ModelClass model= itemList.get(position);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity activity = ((AppCompatActivity)mContext);
            Fragment fragment = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
            // Check if the fragment already exists, if so, just update it
            if (fragment != null) {
                DataFragment dataFragment = (DataFragment) fragment;
                dataFragment.replaceData(model);
            }
            else { // Create new instance
                DataFragment dataFragment= new DataFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment,dataFragment)
                        .commit();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("model", model);
                dataFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!